# How to refresh page after deleting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

When I click on the delete button I can delete the item from the table, but I need to refresh the page manually. How can I get it to refresh automatically?

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";  

const EmployeesList = () => {

const[employees, setEmployees] =  useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  },[])

  const init = () => {
    employeeService.getAll()
    .then(response => {
      setEmployees(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Something wrong', error);
    })
  }

  const deleteSweetAlert = (id) => {
    Swal.fire({  
      title: 'Are you sure?',  
      text: 'User will have Admin Privileges',  
      icon: 'warning',  
      showCancelButton: true,  
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',  
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',  
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes!'  
    }).then(result => { 
        if(result.value) {
          employeeService.remove(id);
          init();
        }
      })
      .catch(error =>{
        console.log('something wrong ',error);
    })
  }
```

The button:

```
<button className="btn btn-danger ml-2" onClick={() => {deleteSweetAlert(employee.id)}}>Delete</button>
```

Comment: Do you mean the reloading of the page by browser?

Comment: you need to update the `employees` by calling the `setEmployees` once the record is deleted.

Comment: i mean the function was successfully deleted but I have to reload, to show the record was gone, so what code do I need to reload? @Oleg

Comment: please give me the code, that you mean @Thinker

Comment: Does  the employeeService.remove(id); is async action?

Comment: No, it's just like this, @Oleg

const remove = id => {
    return httpClient.delete(`/employees/${id}`);
}
export default {remove}

Comment: it is async call, you have to await it. Might be like this  employeeService.remove(id).then(init)

Answer (score 0):

```
location.reload(false);
```

This method takes an optional parameter which by default is set to `false`. If set to `true`, the browser will do a complete page refresh from the server and not from the cached version of the page.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router v5, you can use useHistory hook

```
const EmployeesList = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const reload = () => {
    history.go(0);
  }
}
```

If you are using react-router v6, you can use useNavigate hook

```
const EmployeesList = () => {
  const navigate= useNavigate();
  const reload = () => {
    navigate(0);
  }
}
```

However, consider if you really need to reload the page or if you can rerender your components without reloading the page

Answer (score 0):

You can use react useEffect depencies to auto reload the information of employees

Like this...

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";  

const EmployeesList = () => {

const[employees, setEmployees] =  useState([]);

const[deleted,setDeleted ] =  useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    init();
  },[deleted])

  const init = () => {
    employeeService.getAll()
    .then(response => {
      setEmployees(response.data);
      setDeleted(prev=>prev+1) 
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Something wrong', error);
    })
  }

  const deleteSweetAlert = (id) => {
    Swal.fire({  
      title: 'Are you sure?',  
      text: 'User will have Admin Privileges',  
      icon: 'warning',  
      showCancelButton: true,  
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',  
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',  
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes!'  
    }).then(result => { 
        if(result.value) {
          employeeService.remove(id);
          init();
        }
      })
      .catch(error =>{
        console.log('something wrong ',error);
    })
  }
```

In react useEffect() hook get called very first time & the depencies passed to useEffect changes

Its is a dirty trick to make this automate

Answer (score 0):

I guess you code isn't working because you are not awaiting your delete response. Try this:-

```
const deleteSweetAlert = (id) => {
    Swal.fire({  
      title: 'Are you sure?',  
      text: 'User will have Admin Privileges',  
      icon: 'warning',  
      showCancelButton: true,  
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',  
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',  
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes!'  
    }).then(async result => { 
        if(result.value) {
          await employeeService.remove(id);
          init();
        }
      })
      .catch(error =>{
        console.log('something wrong ',error);
    })
  }
```